# Google Map not fully load in OSClass

Tags: google-maps, osclass

I'm having following codes in `osclass\oc-content\themes\modern\item.php`,

```
<strong class="share"><a href="#" id="map" rel="nofollow"><?php _e('Map', 'modern'); ?></a></strong>

<strong class="share"><a href="#" id="photo" rel="nofollow"><?php _e('Photo Gallery', 'modern'); ?></a></strong>

<div class="map" style="display:none;">
    <?php osc_run_hook('location'); ?> 
</div>

    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-light image" >
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">                        
            <?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
                <?php if( osc_count_item_resources() > 0 ) { ?>
                    <?php for ( $i = 0; osc_has_item_resources(); $i++ ) { if (osc_resource_for() == 2 ) {  ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" width="100%" height="240px;" alt="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" />
                    <?php } } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } osc_reset_resources();  ?>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

and JavaScript code is,

```
$("#photo").click(function() {      
    $(".image").css("display","block");
    $(".map").css("display","none");
});

$("#map").click(function() {
    $(".map").css("display","block");
    $(".image").css("display","none");
});
```

here photo is loading as good. But map makes following problem when I click `#map`.

[image]

If I load map at 1st and set `display:none;` to `.image` means, map will be loaded as fully and good.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested version 3.1 and it's working on my localhost